# Multiple instances of VS Code

Tags: angular, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I've been using VS Code for my angular project and I have added some extensions which are specific for angular. now I've started to develop React project in vs code where I need to use react specific extensions.
is there any way to use different instances of VS Code for different projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create different workspace

File ---> save workspace as

create new workspace for react project

you can disable the angular extensions

[image]